# view not reaching controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this simple mvc app wants a radio button, text input works but radio button not giving me a return, for example, theres 3 buttons (red, blue, green) and if I choose 'red' then viewbag.sup is going to return 'red chosen!' but even though I run this and check 'red' nothing happens, here's what I got:

View (Search.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.RadioButton("color", "red", new { id = "isRed" })
@Html.RadioButton("color", "blue", true)
@Html.RadioButton("color", "green")


}
<p>@ViewBag.Sup</p>
```

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
public ActionResult Search(string color)
    {


        if (color == "red")
        {
            ViewBag.Sup = "red chosen!";
        }



        return View("Search"); 
    }
```

this looks good right? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use FormMethod.Post ?

Comment: So what problems are you having? (and `return View("Search")` does not return a model to the view). If you added `<div>@ViewBag.Sup</div>` in the view, it will display `"red chosen!"` if you select the first radio button and submit the form.

Comment: Now you have changed the code to redirect to another method. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @StephenMuecke still doesent work :/

Comment: What are you expecting? Your now redirecting to another view. If you change it back to `return View("Search"); ` i will work fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke changed to 'Search' still doesent work :/

Comment: Of course it does.

Comment: @StephenMuecke checked again... it does not work, HomeController.cs, Index.cshtml

Comment: You have shown a `Search` view, not an `Index` view so not sure what you doing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I check 'red' , return <p>viewbag.sup</p>, this is what I'm trying to do but it just wont do anything :/

Comment: The code works fine (and I assume you do actually have a submit button in the view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mechanism to actually submit the form. For example you could add a button to do that within the form:

```
<button type="submit"/>
```

Alternatively add a change event handler to the radio buttons that will submit the form (I've used JQuery here, which you almost certainly have loaded if you've used a standard MVC project template, although there are various other ways to attach such a handler to the radio button elements):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { id = "SearchForm" }))
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
        $("#SearchForm").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: nailed it in the fkn head, worked beautifully, can I do this for check boxes too? I don't want to create another stackoverflow post on how to submit drop down lists, etc.